# How to write laravel query with left join and a inner join?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have following tables, and want to do left join with a condition and another inner join from the left joined table,

User table

```
  
id  |  name  
 1     john  
 2     sam  
 3     cecil
```

Roles table

```
  
id | name  
 1  admin  
 2  editor
```

model_has_roles table

```
role_id  | model_type | model_id
  1         App\User       1
  2         App\User       2
```

**What I want**

Do a left join between user table and model_has_roles table on user.id and model_has_roles.model_id column, if **model_type is 'App\User'** and then another inner join between Roles table and model_has_roles table for role_id and Roles.id column. So result should be like this,

```
id | name | role

 1   john   admin
 2   sam    editor
 3   cecil   -
```

I tried following query but not working correctly,

```
 DB::table('users')->select('id', 'name', 'email', 'created_at', 'role_id')
            ->leftJoin('model_has_roles', 'model_has_roles.model_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->where('model_has_roles.model_type', '=', 'App\User')
            ->paginate(1);
```

If you can please help me to write an eloquent query for this.

Thanks

P.S: Actually, I'm using spatie/laravel-permission, and trying to get all the users with their role name.

Comment: Why you don't use their built-in functions like `$user->getPermissionsViaRoles();`?

Comment: What will happen if I have like 50 users and want to call this method 50 times when listing all users? Will it cause to degrade performance? That's what I thought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work just fine:

```
App\User::with('roles')->get();
```

Comment: Yes you saved me!! This worked for me, 
        $roles = Role::all();
        $users = User::with('roles')->paginate(1);

Comment: Also helped me to get roles accessible in vue template.